# Failed to emit module for System.Runtime is being shown as error when trying to Hot Reload a Xamarin Forms UWP project

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, hot-reload

Hot reload is failing for Xamarin Forms UWP. I deployed my application in debug mode, and it said **Xaml Hot Reload connected**. But when I updated some code, saved and tried to hot reload with the fire icon in Visual Studio. Edit and Continue error was prompted.

Then in the error list came this:

```
CS7038: Failed to emit module 'ProjectName': Changing the version of an assembly reference is not allowed during debugging:
'System.Runtime, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' changed version to '4.1.2.0'.
```

[Hot reload settings screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BR2aY.png)

Xamarin Forms version: 5.0.0.2125

Comment: what code have you changed？ And if the error occurs if you just change sth like text or color?

Comment: @AdrainZhu-MSFT I updated an `if` condition. 
When updating the `Xaml` file for color or text the error does not occur.

Comment: could you post relevent code about it?

Comment: I have same issue with my project; I'm using .NET 6 but it says I'm trying to use System.Runtime 5.0.0.0. It's making debugging a lot worse and I have no idea what's causing this...

Comment: Seeing this myself on a monogame + WPF app, no idea the cause.